# He who isn't a he, she, or a it

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking

**H**e can look up to the skies and dream.
**H**e is bestowed with the greatest title of all, which nothing can claim to deserve.
**H**e is not necessarily a he.
Neither is he necessarily a she.
But definitely not an it.
**H**e exists in diversity
**H**e has many forms.
But truly,
**H**e is one and the same.

### *Who is this enigma?*

Comment: Can I clarify that the wording is correct? Line one currently means 'He is ALWAYS not a he.' And line two currently means 'He doesn't HAVE TO BE a she.'

Comment: I've updated the wording slightly to match your intent. If this breaks the puzzle, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I just got here so I don't know but, I would suspect the abuse of edits might be the cause. The original puzzle seems to have changed a LOT and many times. Also, possibly the puzzle was way too easy. Feels like it is just a plain description and nothing is cryptic. Just my opinion though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it:

> A human?

He can look up to the skies and dream (self-explanatory)
He is bestowed with the greatest title of all, which none can claim to deserve

> Being the most intelligent animal

He is not necessarily a he
Neither is he necessarily a she
But definitely not an it (definition)

> Males, females, LGBTIQ+

He exists in diversity
He has many forms

> There exist many races

But truly,
He is one and the same

> Humans all descend from a common ancestor

Comment: Kudos! You got the answer. But, the exact word I had in mind was MAN. The word MAN or MANKIND takes 'he' as pronoun. It refers to people in general, regardless of gender. The word is gender-neutral. Nothing except a human being is a Man, obviously.

Answer (score 7):

You are talking about

> The pronoun "I"

He is not necessarily a he.
Neither is he necessarily a she.

> "I" can be used by any of them (either male or female).

But definitely not an it.

> The pronoun "It" is used for an object. "I" cannot be used for an object.

He can look up to the skies and dream.
He is bestowed with the greatest title of all, which nothing can claim to deserve.

> An 'eye' can look and it's a great gift for us.

NOTE: I can't really think of anything after the edit of question.

Comment: Do you mean pronoun?

Comment: well, you are on the right track, but this is not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: As I said, you are near, so don't delete this answer. Very, very near to be frank.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine Edited.

Comment: @manshu The last explanation is better now, but you contradict yourself. You already know the fully correct answer (i.e. the word), yet you don't realise you know it. Read your own sentence carefully.

Comment: @manshu The right word will perfectly match most of your description; you only need to alter a bit here and there. I told you-your guess is very, very near to the correct answer.

Comment: @manshu I added more lines to the riddle.

Comment: I guess it is just **pronoun**. Nothing too specific after that, I think.

Answer (score 2):

It may be

> [Helium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium)

Because

> 1. Repeated embolden capital H. 
>
>
>  2. "He is not necessarily a he.Neither is he necessarily a she." Helium is an element; not a person. 
>
>
>  3. "But definitely not an it." Helium; just like "water"; is an uncountable noun. So we can't write "it is a helium". 
>  
>  
>  4. "He is one and the same"... As 'element', there is no two helium. As 'atoms' , All helium atoms are the same (until we consider isotopy). 
>
>
>  5.  He has many forms... gaseous, liquid, superfluid. Exists in diversity... found in planet and stars (such as sun).
>
>    Helium is found in "sky" in that sense Sun is on the sky, and sun contains helium. As well as Earth's atmosphere contains little bit helium.  Also a baloon filled with helium would float "up" from we at ground level. 
>
>
>  6. Google shows there is a book named [Helium Dream , by Dan James](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001KRR15E) . (Though I've not read this book). So helium exists in Dream. 
>
>
>  So the answer is going to be Helium (He)

Comment: What about 'it is a helium **atom**'

Comment: Amazing guess! Unfortunately, not the answer. I see you've made an effort, so I'm gonna award you with loads of upvotes!

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine Thank you for your appreciation. I did not wrote it as a confirmed answer but as a possibility.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused I am a a Bengali too! (But also, a Bangladeshi, not an indian.)

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine oh that boundaries don't have any real existence.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused True. :-)

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine Please visit [this](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/26739/how-would-it-be-if-a-se-site-is-created-on-bangla-bengali-language), proposed by me on Area51

Answer (score -1):

Can it be

> God

Because

> 1) He is the supreme and bestowed with that title
>  2) we can't tell the gender of God
>  3) he is omnipresent everywhere in every form yet there is only one god